# Terraform Include parent uri with dynamic parameter in child uri for AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I want to create a endpoint like **user/<user_id>/info** through aws_api_gateway using terraform

I am able to create endpoint till /user/<user_id>

But how to include <user_id> in the resource for "info"

Here is the code for "info" part:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "info" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.app.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.user.id
  path_part   = "info"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "info" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.app.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.info.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "info" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.app.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.info.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.info.http_method
  type                 = "HTTP_PROXY"
  uri                  = "http://root_api/user/<user_id>/info"
```

When I try this, the url for info resolves to **http://root_api/user/<user_id>/info**.
Any help on how to inject <user_id> in this url ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Terraform interpolates variables in strings: [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings).

In your case:

```
uri = "http://root_api/user/${aws_api_gateway_resource.user.id}/info"
```

Comment: It should be with the curly braces :)  `"http://root_api/user/${aws_api_gateway_resource.user.id}/info"`

Comment: Thanks, just a typo, fixed in answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. 
I also found a way to add any dynamic parameter to a resource by adding ```request_parameters = {
    "integration.request.path.user_id" = "method.request.path.user_id",
  }``` This way all the dynamic parameters that your uri need can be accessed in a resource no matter where they are in the ancestor chain

Comment: Above code must also ve included in the aws_api_gateway_method like
```
request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.user_id" = true,
}
```

Comment: Ah, only now I realized what you were actually asking about. So I did not actually answer your question, although I hope it at least guided you in the right direction :) Feel free to provide your solution as a separate answer.

Comment: Yes will post the answer

Answer (score 1):

Figured Out the answer. This makes you accept any dynamic parameter into your integation uri no matter from where they appear in the ancestor chain

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "info" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.app.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.user.id
  path_part   = "info"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "info" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.app.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.info.id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
  request_parameters   = 
  {
   "method.request.path.user_id" = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "info" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.app.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.info.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.info.http_method
  type                 = "HTTP_PROXY"
  uri                  = "http://root_api/user/<user_id>/info"
  request_parameters   = 
  {
   "integration.request.path.user_id" = "method.request.path.user_id"
  }
}
```